# Which jar I should add to eclipse project for org.apache.catalina.websocket?

Tags: tomcat, websocket

I am trying to add WebSocket support to my J2EE server (running on Tomcat 7, but soon moving to 8).
I do my development in eclipse and it cannot find org.apache.catalina.websocket. Which jar contains this package and where can I get it from?  I looked into catalina.jar, websocket-api.jar and tomcat-websocket.jar from Apache/tomcat 8 and it is not there.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Look at tomcat-websocket.jar again. The package got renamed to `org.apache.tomcat.websocket`.

Comment: The Tomcat 8 tomcat-websocket.jar contains org.apache.tomcat.websocket but the code has been refactored, so Tomcat 7 code will not work